# Keydown/up events with React Hooks not working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, keyboard-events

I'm trying to create arrow based keyboard controls for a game I'm working on. Of course I'm trying to stay up to date with React so I wanted to create a function component and use hooks. I've created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vus4nrfe/1/) for my buggy component.

It's almost working as expected, except when I press a lot of the arrow keys at the same time. Then it seems like some `keyup` events aren't triggered. It could also be that the 'state' is not updated properly.

Which I do like this:

```
  const ALLOWED_KEYS = ['ArrowUp', 'ArrowDown', 'ArrowLeft', 'ArrowRight']
  const [pressed, setPressed] = React.useState([])

  const handleKeyDown = React.useCallback(event => {
    const { key } = event
    if (ALLOWED_KEYS.includes(key) && !pressed.includes(key)) {
      setPressed([...pressed, key])
    }
  }, [pressed])

  const handleKeyUp = React.useCallback(event => {
    const { key } = event
    setPressed(pressed.filter(k => k !== key))
  }, [pressed])

  React.useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown)
    document.addEventListener('keyup', handleKeyUp)

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown)
      document.removeEventListener('keyup', handleKeyUp)
    }
  })
```

I have the idea that I'm doing it correctly, but being new to hooks it is very likely that this is where the problem is. Especially since I've re-created the same component as a class based component:
https://jsfiddle.net/vus4nrfe/

And that seems to work fine...

Comment: If you add an empty array as the second parameter to `useEffect`, does that fix it?  `useEffect(() => {...}, [])`

Comment: You could take a look at [useKeyPress](https://usehooks.com/useKeyPress/)

Comment: @larz It kind of does, except it only works for one key at a time. It work when having 2 keys pressed at the same time. https://jsfiddle.net/9c85gdxk/

Comment: @Vencovsky: that looks promising, especially the multi-keypress example. I also like the way how it's abstracted as some kind of custom hook.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are 3 key things to do to make it work as expected just like your class component.

As others mentioned for `useEffect` you need to add an `[]` as a dependency array which will trigger only once the `addEventLister` functions.

The second thing which is the main issue is that you are not mutating the `pressed` array's **previous state** in functional component as you did in class component, just like below:

```
// onKeyDown event
this.setState(prevState => ({
   pressed: [...prevState.pressed, key],
}))

// onKeyUp event
this.setState(prevState => ({
   pressed: prevState.pressed.filter(k => k !== key),
}))
```

You need to update in functional one as the following:

```
// onKeyDown event
setPressedKeys(previousPressedKeys => [...previousPressedKeys, key]);

// onKeyUp event
setPressedKeys(previousPressedKeys => previousPressedKeys.filter(k => k !== key));
```

The third thing is that the definition of the `onKeyDown` and `onKeyUp` events have been moved inside of `useEffect` so you don't need to use `useCallback`.

The mentioned things solved the issue on my end. Please find the following working GitHub repository what I've made which works as expected:

> https://github.com/norbitrial/react-keydown-useeffect-componentdidmount

Find a working JSFiddle version if you like it better here:

> https://jsfiddle.net/0aogqbyp/

The [essential part](https://github.com/norbitrial/react-keydown-useeffect-componentdidmount/blob/master/src/KeyDownFunctional.jsx) from the repository, fully working component:

```
const KeyDownFunctional = () => {
    const [pressedKeys, setPressedKeys] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const onKeyDown = ({key}) => {
            if (Consts.ALLOWED_KEYS.includes(key) && !pressedKeys.includes(key)) {
                setPressedKeys(previousPressedKeys => [...previousPressedKeys, key]);
            }
        }

        const onKeyUp = ({key}) => {
            if (Consts.ALLOWED_KEYS.includes(key)) {
                setPressedKeys(previousPressedKeys => previousPressedKeys.filter(k => k !== key));
            }
        }

        document.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown);
        document.addEventListener('keyup', onKeyUp);

        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown);
            document.removeEventListener('keyup', onKeyUp);
        }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, []);

    return <>
        <h3>KeyDown Functional Component</h3>
        <h4>Pressed Keys:</h4>

        {pressedKeys.map(e => <span key={e} className="key">{e}</span>)}
    </>
}
```

The reason why I'm using `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` for the `useEffect` is because I don't want to reattach the events every single time once the `pressed` or `pressedKeys` array is changing.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, wonderful! Me not using the previous state was the last uncaught problem. (I see you also forgot it in your fiddle for the keyup, here's the final fiddle for completeness: https://jsfiddle.net/oh8x4smp/1/) Thanks for all the time you put in! I think my use of `useCallback` wasn't necessary at all. Somebody else mentioned it as well. Just an arrow function seems to work fine. Even outside `useEffect`. Is there any specific reason it has to be inside `useEffect`?

Comment: @thomasjonas Great, happy to help! The reason is that you don't need anywhere else, just to attach or detach the event which is handled inside of `useEffect`. I like to create functions with the minimal scope what I can achieve if I'm not using them anywhere else. I hope this clarifies.

Comment: Aha, that makes sense! One more thing: I've noticed a lot of unnecessary re-renders. It seems like `!pressedKeys.includes(key)` in the `onKeyDown` handler does not work as the `pressedKeys` value is not updated. I assume that's because `pressedKeys` is not in the dependencies array of `useEffect`, right?

Comment: I know this is an old post but what if the user wanted manually press the button with a mouse or touch event? You can’t call the function inside of useEffect so how would this be done?

Comment: Hallelujah! I've been looking at how to update state in conjunction with `document.addEventListener('keydown', callback)` for hours. I read a lot of articles about useCallback and refs, but it turns out I just needed to pass the state setter function a callback in the `document`'s event listener.

Answer (score 4):

User @Vencovsky mentioned the [useKeyPress recipe](https://usehooks.com/useKeyPress/) by Gabe Ragland. Implementing this made everything work as expected. The useKeyPress recipe:

```
// Hook
const useKeyPress = (targetKey) => {
  // State for keeping track of whether key is pressed
  const [keyPressed, setKeyPressed] = React.useState(false)

  // If pressed key is our target key then set to true
  const downHandler = ({ key }) => {
    if (key === targetKey) {
      setKeyPressed(true)
    }
  }

  // If released key is our target key then set to false
  const upHandler = ({ key }) => {
    if (key === targetKey) {
      setKeyPressed(false)
    }
  }

  // Add event listeners
  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', downHandler)
    window.addEventListener('keyup', upHandler)
    // Remove event listeners on cleanup
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('keydown', downHandler)
      window.removeEventListener('keyup', upHandler)
    }
  }, []) // Empty array ensures that effect is only run on mount and unmount

  return keyPressed
}
```

You can then use that "hook" as follows:

```
const KeyboardControls = () => {
  const isUpPressed = useKeyPress('ArrowUp')
  const isDownPressed = useKeyPress('ArrowDown')
  const isLeftPressed = useKeyPress('ArrowLeft')
  const isRightPressed = useKeyPress('ArrowRight')

  return (
    <div className="keyboard-controls">
      <div className={classNames('up-button', isUpPressed && 'pressed')} />
      <div className={classNames('down-button', isDownPressed && 'pressed')} />
      <div className={classNames('left-button', isLeftPressed && 'pressed')} />
      <div className={classNames('right-button', isRightPressed && 'pressed')} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Complete fiddle can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/upym1t4s/2/).

The difference with my code is that it use hooks and state *per key* instead of all the keys at once. I'm not sure why that would matter though. Would be great if somebody could explain that.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help and made the hooks concept clearer for me. And thanks for @Vencovsky for pointing me to the usehooks.com website by Gabe Ragland.

Answer (score 2):

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown)
  document.addEventListener('keyup', handleKeyUp)

  return () => {
    document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown)
    document.removeEventListener('keyup', handleKeyUp)
  }
}, [handleKeyDown, handleKeyUp]); // <---- Add this deps array
```

You need to add the handlers as dependencies to the `useEffect`, otherwise it gets called on every render.

Also, make sure your deps array is not empty `[]`, because your handlers could change based on the value of `pressed`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to help unfortunately. I still get stuck keys. When I use the empty deps array it doesn't get stuck keys, but it only works for 1 key at a time. So I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the `pressed` state and some dependencies somewhere that I'm not handling properly. I'm now looking into [useKeyPress](https://usehooks.com/useKeyPress/) as suggested by @Vencovsky

Answer (score 2):

All the solutions I found were pretty bad. For instance, the solutions in this thread only allow you to hold down 2 buttons, or they simply don't work like a lot of the use-hooks libraries.

After working on this for a long time with @asafaviv from #Reactiflux I think this is my favorite solution:

```js
import { useState, useLayoutEffect } from 'react'

const specialKeys = [
  `Shift`,
  `CapsLock`,
  `Meta`,
  `Control`,
  `Alt`,
  `Tab`,
  `Backspace`,
  `Escape`,
]

const useKeys = () => {
  if (typeof window === `undefined`) return [] // Bail on SSR

  const [keys, setKeys] = useState([])

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const downHandler = ({ key, shiftKey, repeat }) => {
      if (repeat) return // Bail if they're holding down a key
      setKeys(prevKeys => {
        return [...prevKeys, { key, shiftKey }]
      })
    }
    const upHandler = ({ key, shiftKey }) => {
      setKeys(prevKeys => {
        return prevKeys.filter(k => {
          if (specialKeys.includes(key))
            return false // Special keys being held down/let go of in certain orders would cause keys to get stuck in state
          return JSON.stringify(k) !== JSON.stringify({ key, shiftKey }) // JS Objects are unique even if they have the same contents, this forces them to actually compare based on their contents
        })
      })
    }

    window.addEventListener(`keydown`, downHandler)
    window.addEventListener(`keyup`, upHandler)
    return () => {
      // Cleanup our window listeners if the component goes away
      window.removeEventListener(`keydown`, downHandler)
      window.removeEventListener(`keyup`, upHandler)
    }
  }, [])

  return keys.map(x => x.key) // return a clean array of characters (including special characters )
}

export default useKeys
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of this snippet implemented in a component, please?

Comment: @cthorpe Actually, I have no idea how to use it... https://codesandbox.io/s/absolutely-no-idea-budl8 I have no idea what React is doing half the time. I can collect all the keys using that hook, but actually making use of them seems impossible.

I ended up using a different approach on my own project that seems to be working where I collect them with a timestamp.

If anyone can help debug this! PLEASE DO. I'll update the answer and the demo.

Comment: Thanks- I sympathize! I, too, ended up going a different route using 'react-hotkeys-hook':

`import { useHotkeys } from 'react-hotkeys-hook';

export default function MyApp({ Component }) {
  const addBodyClass = cName => document.body.classList.add(cName);
  const removeBodyClass = cName=> document.body.classList.remove(cName);
  const setHotkey = (hotkey, cName) => {
    useHotkeys(hotkey, () => document.body.classList.contains(cName) ? removeBodyClass(cName) : addBodyClass(cName));
  };

  setHotkey("ctrl+.", 'exampleClass');

  return <Component} />;
}`

Answer (score 1):

`useEffect` runs on every render, resulting on adding/removing your listeners on each keypress. This could potential lead to a key press/release without a listener attached.

Suppling an empty array `[]` as second parameter to `useEffect`, React will know that this effect does not depend on any of the props/state values so it never needs to re-run, attaching and cleaning up your listeners once

```js
  React.useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown)
    document.addEventListener('keyup', handleKeyUp)

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown)
      document.removeEventListener('keyup', handleKeyUp)
    }
  }, [])
```

Comment: Good to know that I should use dependencies! It only slightly helped: keys don't get stuck anymore, but it doesn't work for multiple/2 keys at the same time. See updated fiddle :https://jsfiddle.net/9c85gdxk/

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're [Breaking the Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html#breaking-the-rules-of-hooks):

> Do not call Hooks inside functions passed to `useMemo`, `useReducer`, or `useEffect`.

You're calling the `setPressed` hook inside a function passed to `useCallback`, which basically uses `useMemo` under the hood.

> `useCallback(fn, deps)` is equivalent to `useMemo(() => fn, deps)`.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback

See if removing the `useCallback` in favor of a plain arrow function solves your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help. It also doesn't make a difference, but I do believe you're right with me breaking the rules of hooks. I'll keep them plain arrow functions.