# onKeyDown/onKeyUp not firing when pressing the Tab button on Android

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, events, keyboard

When using GBoard keyboard (at least), it appears that `onKeyDown` and `onKeyUp` are not firing when pressing the <kbd>Tab</kbd> button (the one at the bottom-right corner, with an arrow).

This is causing an issue on a React app we have, where this button is behaving exactly like pressing the <kbd>Tab</kbd> button on a real keyboard, but we're able to suppress its behavior on desktops and other devices.

I've confirmed that this is not a React issue, as if I try exactly the same with the below, the event isn't fired when pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> on Android/GBoard:

```
<input id="text-field" type="text" placeholder="Press Tab here" />
<input id="text-field-2" type="text" />
<script>
$('#text-field').on('keydown', function (e) {
    alert(e.key);
});
</script>
```

Tested on Android 10 & Android 11, using Google Chrome with GBoard.

**Any idea how to handle the pressing of that button?**
**Is this intended/documented?**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43503964/onkeydown-event-not-working-on-divs-in-react) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59546928/keydown-up-events-with-react-hooks-not-working-properly) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47478453/keyup-keydown-and-keypress-events-not-working-on-mobile) help? Probably [the issue still persists](https://github.com/react-tags/react-tags/issues/199).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But please note, the events DO fire for all other keys. Just not for this "Tab" key. Those issues you linked appear to be more that "doesn't fire for any key". Cheers.